# Cron Job command - understanding

Tags: linux, cronjob

I am using a cron job, received from one of my suppliers, in order to create/update the products data, stock, status, in my Woocommerce website.

I have installed their plugin, all verification are green, but I have a problem:
the cron job run only 10 jobs/hour (no matter the time chosen).

I put *, 5 minutes, 10, 15, 20... It is the same for all. So, 10 jobs, it is stopping, and after 1 hour, again 10 jobs and is stopping.
The problem is that the queue is bigger (more than 10 jobs are added per hour), so I remaining behind with the updates.

I starting to say that I am completely novice with the cron jobs.

The command received from the supplier is:

```
/usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/wc_process_import_itakeit.ro.lockfile /usr/bin/curl https://itakeit.ro/wcmipconnector/readfiles >> /home/itakeit/public_html/wp-content/uploads/mip-connector/logs/process_import_cron.log
```

But, if I put on the browser this link and press enter: `https://itakeit.ro/wcmipconnector/readfiles`
I see in the log files that automatically the log is starting to show activity. 10 jobs, and then is stopping. If I repeat this action, always 10 jobs are running. All 10 jobs are taking maximum 2 minutes for finishing.

Question1: What is the difference of the commands between the command from supplier and the web link?

Question2: When I use the web link, and I see activity on the log file, is possible to be a fake activity? I mean to not do what I suppose that is doing?

Question3: Is any other better command?

Question4: Is something bad on my server settings who make the cron jobs run only 10 jobs instead of more?

Question5: Is something bad on my server settings who make the cron jobs run just once per hour instead to respect the timeline: */5 ; */10.....?

**PS: I put another cron job command with this command:
How can I create a cron job that use the web link and run by 10 minutes?**

Something like this sometimes works and sometimes not:

```
wget -q -O – https://itakeit.ro/wcmipconnector/readfiles/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

**It looks like the workflow (not the Cron) is the Issue here.**

The workflow is using `/usr/bin/flock` to try taking a lock on `/tmp/wc_process_import_itakeit.ro.lockfile` & then execute `curl` which is triggering the Data Update Process in the Background.

The Cron is triggering correctly , but the workflow is messing up the things.
Command `flock` is using `-n` which will try to take the lock & exit when some other Process is holding the lock.

**Suggestion I can give without knowing the Workflow Details is :**

Command `/usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/w....` must be changed to this Command `/usr/bin/flock --timeout 1800 /tmp/w....` which will make `flock` wait for the lock for 30 minutes maximum. This will allow all Processes to Execute within the hour & get ready for the next hour.

**This way , all Processes will get the lock & will Execute Correctly !**

UPDATE , which is the outcome of looking into various files :

It seems that :
(1) the file `/tmp/wc_process_import_itakeit.ro.lockfile` is missing.
(2) the file `/home/itakeit/public_html/wp-content/uploads/mip-connector/logs/process_import_cron.log` shows timeouts or misconfigurations or other Issues.

With that , we can Conclusively see that the Issue is due to Workflow , not Cron. The ADMIN will be able to look into this to resolve it.

Meanwhile , the webbrowser trigger seems to work. With that , here are two temporary work-arounds :
**(WORK-AROUND 1)** The Cron must not use `flock` : It must run Directly.
Use this Command :

`/usr/bin/curl https://itakeit.ro/wcmipconnector/readfiles >> /home/itakeit/public_html/wp-content/uploads/mip-connector/logs/process_import_cron.log`

Let it run every 10 minutes.
When the SYSTEM ADMIN resolves the Configuration Issue , then you should move back to the `flock` variant.

**(WORK-AROUND 2)** Go to `/tmp` & Execute `touch /tmp/wc_process_import_itakeit.ro.lockfile` to let `flock` function , which will then run the `curl` on the web-address.
Let the Cron use `flock` with `-timeout 240` ( not `-n` )
Let that Execute every 10 minutes.

When the SYSTEM ADMIN resolves the Configuration Issue , then you should check to verify the `flock` Parameters.

**These are temporary : SYSTEM ADMIN should look into these when the Configuration Issue is resolved eventually.**

Comment: Hello, I wrote the command (on 10 minutes, not on 6), but is the same :((
For example, the cron job run at 10:20, finish 10 jobs at 10:22. The next cron job is starting at 11:30 (I saw that he calculates 10 minutes over the initial 10:20). Then starts at 12:40..13:50...etc

I used also the above rule of Romeo...nothing changed.

What I realized (because I tried to create a cron job with my link, at an external website. He don't run, I mean, run, but do nothing. I tried myself on incognito mode to run the job, and don't work. It's working only in Chrome where I'm logged in into the cpanel.

Comment: What timeout value was used ? Does `/tmp/wc_process_import_itakeit.ro.lockfile` Exist ? What are the other relevant contents of Directory `/tmp/` ? What Debug Output is available through log file `/home/itakeit/public_html/wp-content/uploads/mip-connector/logs/process_import_cron.log` ? What is `ps` Output when Processes are running ?

Comment: Hello,

/tmp/wc_process_import_itakeit.ro.lockfile don't exist.
In the tmp folder is almost nothing :( interesting:
Awstats
pma_template_compiles_itakeit(with a folder twig. Alot of php files. Last created on 24.12

Comment: part 2
Inside is looking that are reefering to the subject.:
ORDER BY `wpj7_mipconnector_file_log`.`date_add` DESC";s:12:"repeat_cells";i:100;s:8:"max_rows";i:25;s:3:"pos";i:0;s:6:"pftext";s:1:"P";s:18:"relational_display";s:1:"K";s:9:"geoOption";s:4:"GEOM";s:14:"display_binary";b:1;}s:32:"c8b9c45ccbb52b9cb0dcbc057ae5f537";a:8:{s:3:"sql";s:99:"SELECT * FROM `wpj7_mipconnector_file_log` 
(sorry, I don't understand more than a copy paste).

Comment: part 3

Related to log file, almost all lines have this syntax "{"Code":200,"Message":"Ok","Data":[]}{"Code":200,"Message":"Ok","Data":[]}" repeat many many times
Then, in the end is this: <h2>Request Timeout</h2>
and this: <p>This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

(I believe your question open a possible solution) :)

Comment: Might have to fix the Workflow , Eg make the file `/tmp/wc_process_import_itakeit.ro.lockfile` , Ensure all Packages are installed , user Permissions are Correct , DataBase Servers have the Data , Etc. Essentially , this is not Cron Issue , It is Workflow Issue. Your ADMIN might assist further.

Comment: Thank you Prem. I forward this to the website hosting.

Meanwhile, to not remaining back with the updates, I run manually the link: https://itakeit.ro/wcmipconnector/readfiles

Do you know, why always is working? I mean, when I run this, I have activity, so is ok. How can I use this link, in order to run as cron job, always?

Thank you very much for your help!
Alin

Comment: I have updated the Answer with a work-around , I hope that is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of execution with `flock`. This hold the jobs because of the lock file exist and over the time create huge queue. What you can do:

1. Make `cron` job to run on interval bigger than the execution time of job.
2. As suggested in other answer add timeout so the job expire after some time. This actually is very similar to point 1 because you will get only one job executed for particular interval.
3. Make each run unique and store the output in different file. Or store only "negative" results and assume the rest are OK (code 200). But here you should take care of many files to be combined/purged.

To make job run 10 jobs per hour the record in `cron` need to be something like:

```
*/6 * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/wc_process_import_itakeit.ro.lockfile /usr/bin/curl https://itakeit.ro/wcmipconnector/readfiles >> /home/itakeit/public_html/wp-content/uploads/mip-connector/logs/process_import_cron.log
```